# Sending a single letter using pipes in C

Tags: c

I am trying to send a string using a pipe from parent to child **one character at a time**. In order to do that, I am passing that character to the write statement using a for loop as follows :

```
for(int j=0; j<strlen(str); j++){
    write(fd[WRITE_END], str[j], BUFFER_SIZE);
}
```

However, the code does not compile successfully and shows the following:

```
warning: passing argument 2 of ‘write’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
write(fd[WRITE_END], str[j], BUFFER_SIZE);
```

and

```
note: expected ‘const void *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 extern ssize_t write (int __fd, const void *__buf, size_t __n) __wur;
```

What did I do wrong?
Is it not possible to send single characters using pipes?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation for "write()":

> https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/write.3p.html
>
> ```
> #include <unistd.h>
>
> ssize_t pwrite(int fildes, const void *buf, size_t nbyte,
>            off_t offset);
> ssize_t write(int fildes, const void *buf, size_t nbyte);
> ```

In other words, if you want to write one character, you need to:

- Specify the address of that character, and
- Specify "one byte":

  ```
  for(int j=0; j<strlen(str); j++){
    write(fd[WRITE_END], &str[j], 1);
  }
  ```